# Save file in vbscript with fpdf

Tags: vbscript, fpdf

Sorry, my english isn't good.
I have created a pdf file with fpdf in vbscript but when I try to save it directly on a particular path is opened in the browser. Can I save directly or only opens in the browser ?. This is my code:

```
Dim pdf
Set pdf=CreateJsObject("FPDF")
pdf.CreatePDF
pdf.SetPath("fpdf/")
pdf.SetFont "Arial","B",16
pdf.Open()
pdf.AddPage()
pdf.Cell 40,10,"Hello, world!"
pdf.Close()
filewrite=Server.MapPath("pdf/new.pdf")
pdf.Output filewrite
```